# Customize NotFound exception --- Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Assume a minimal application with a `person` model, a `ModelSerializer` and a corresponding `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`.

Only one entry exists in the database so when requesting `/person/1` the response correctly is:

```
{
  "name": "RandomName1"
}
```

When requesting `/person/2` the response is:

```
{
  "detail": "Not found."
}
```

I want to customize this.

Even though I read the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/) it is not clear how I can customize this.

I should clarify that I am looking to customize this, according to the view. For example `/person/2` should return:

```
{
  "detail": "Person 2 was not found."
}
```

and `/address/3` should return:

```
{
  "detail": "Address 3 was not found."
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to handle responses which have a 404 status code. Modifying the example from the linked documentation:

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response.data['status_code'] == 404:
        try:
            response.data['detail'] = "{name} {id} was not found.".format(
                name=context['view'].verbose_name,
                id=context['kwargs']['id']  # this may need tweaking
            )
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    return response
```

Then add the corresponding `verbose_name` to your view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I request `/person/2` I get a `404 Not Found` status code **not** 401.

Comment: Thank you. However, this is a generic `404` right? I am looking for something specific per view. I apologize I didn't include this in my original question. I have made an update to reflect this.

Comment: @ivan-semochkin Good suggestion. @Demetris You could add the custom message as a view method, then call `context['view'].get_custom_message()`.

Comment: @nimasmi ah accidentally remove my comment. Or you can just add a class variable.

Comment: @ivan-semochkin I've updated, thanks. @Demetris Not sure what the `id` kwarg will be, so you may need to look at `context['args']` and `context['kwargs']`.

Comment: Thank you. One final question. Will the rest of the exceptions be raised correctly? For example `405 Method Not Allowed`?

Comment: The example above tries to insert some extra information only when the exception code is 404. If the insertion fails, the exception response is returned as normal. If the code is not 404, the exception response is returned as normal.